# Importing Dates into R from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, r, date

I am trying to query a SQL Server database to check for the MAX date in one field and to select the next day for input into another process. I am able to query the database and pull back a date, but I can't convert it into a date object.

Here is what I tried:

```
tmpMaxDate <- sqlQuery(dbhandle, 'select MAX([date]) + 1 from dbo.My_Data ')
tmpMaxDate

1 2016-01-02
IsDate(tmpMaxDate)
[1] FALSE

maxDate    <- as.Date(tmpMaxDate)
Error in as.Date.default(tmpMaxDate) : 
  do not know how to convert 'tmpMaxDate' to class “Date”
maxDate
NULL
IsDate(maxDate)
[1] FALSE


maxDate <- as.Date(tmpMaxDate, format = "%Y-%M-%D")
Error in as.Date.default(tmpMaxDate, format = "%Y-%M-%D") : 
  do not know how to convert 'tmpMaxDate' to class “Date”

IsDate(maxDate)
[1] FALSE
maxDate
NULL
```

The packages I am using are RODBC, chron, lubridate, and RSQLserver
I thought I needed to convert to a date object to use the date from SQL Server in R.

Any thoughts on why my date won't convert?  Do I need to convert to be able to use that date to filter data in R?

Comment: What does `class(tmpMaxDat)` shows? Is it a `data.frame`? You need to pass a character string to `as.Date`.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateVar <- sqlQuery(dbhandle,"SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10),GETDATE() + 1,101) as Date")
DateVar
NewDate <- as.Date(DateVar$Date, format = "%m/%d/%y")
NewDate
```

I think the trick for me to was give the date response a column name and then reference the column (being the specific string value needed to convert) name in the conversion.

```
class(NewDate)
```

will show as "Date"